# Find all polynomials $P(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ such that $P(x^2) = P(x)[P(x) - 2x], \forall x \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ such that $$\large P(x^2) = P(x)[P(x) - 2x], \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

It has been a while since I touched on some problems about polynomials. So this is one of them. I have provided my solution below with my reasonings, which could be incorrect or loosely connected.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could come up with a different solution, using a different approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$P(x)=ax^n+bx^m+\text { lower order terms}, \text { where } ab\ne0 \text { and } n>m>1$$

Then comparing terms of degree $n+m$ in $P(x^2)=P(x)\left(P(x)-2x\right)$ gives $0=2ab$ which is impossible. So we can suppose that 
$$P(x)=ax^n+bx+c, n>1.$$
$$ax^{2n}+bx^2+c=\left (ax^n+bx+c\right)\left (ax^n+(b-2)x+c\right).$$

$$a(a-1)x^{2n}+2a(b-1)x^{n+1}+2acx^n+b(b-3)x^2+2c(b-1)x+c(c-1)=0.$$

All coefficients must be zero however note that if $n=2$ then the coefficient of $x^2$ is $2ac+b(b-3)$.

If $a\ne0$, then $a=b=1$ and so $n=2$ and $c=1$.

> $P(x)=x^2+x+1$.

If $a=0$, then $b(b-3)=c(b-1)=0$ and so $c=0$ and $b=0$ or $3$.

> $P(x)=0$ or $3x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $P(x) = c$ is a constant, we have that $c = c(c - 2x), \forall x \in \mathbb R \implies P(x) \equiv 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$.

If $P(x)$ is a linear polynomial, let $P(x) \equiv ax + b$, where $a, b \in \mathbb R$ and $a \ne 0$. We have that $$ax^2 + b = (ax + b)[(a - 2)x + b], \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

$$\iff a(a - 3)x^2 + 2(a - 1)bx + b(b - 1) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

$$\implies a(a - 3) = (a - 1)b = b(b - 1) = 0 \implies (a, b) = (3, 0) \implies P(x) \equiv 3x, \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

If $n = \deg P \ge 2$, it is clear that the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ is $1$.

Let $P(x) = x^n + Q(x)$. We have that $\deg Q \le n - 1$ and $Q \not\equiv 0$. We have that $$x^{2n} + Q(x^2) = [x^n + Q(x)][x(x^{n - 1} - 2) + Q(x)], \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

$$\implies Q(x^2) = -2x^{n + 1} + 2x(x^{n - 1} - 1)Q(x) + [Q(x)]^2$$

Notice that $\deg 2x(x^{n - 1} - 1)Q(x) > \deg [Q(x)]^2,\, \deg Q(x^2)$

$\implies \deg 2x(x^{n - 1} - 1)Q(x) = \deg (-2x^{n + 1}) \implies \deg Q = 1$

It is also obvious that the leading coefficient of $Q(x)$ is $3$.

Let $P(x) = x^n + 3x + c$, where $n, c \in \mathbb R$ and $n \ge 2$. We have that

$$x^{2n} + 3x^2 + c = (x^n + 3x + c)(x^n + x + c), \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

$$\implies 4x^{n + 1} + 2cx^n + 4cx + c(c - 1) = 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

There aren't any values of $c$ satisfying the above condition.

So the polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying the equations are $P(x) \equiv \left\{\begin{align} 0\\ 3x \end{align} \right., \forall x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Actually **It is also obvious that the leading coefficient of $Q(x)$ is $1$** and this gives a new solution: $P(X)=X^2+X+1$.